# OS X app that runs on 10.6 to 10.9 doesn't run on 10.10 (Yosemite) -- why?

Tags: xcode, osx-yosemite

For over a year now, I've been using XCode 4.5 to build an app using the OS X 10.7 sdk, with target deployment to 10.6.

The app runs perfectly well on 10.6, 10.7, 10.8, and 10.9.  But when I run it on 10.10, I get a message in the Console saying "Cannot enforce a hard page-zero" for the app.

Googling "Cannot enforce a hard page-zero" returns nothing helpful.

Does anyone have any idea what this means?

One useful bit of information is that building the app with XCode 5 doesn't result in the problem, so I'm thinking it has something to do with the older XCode 4.5.

I'd rather stick with the older XCode if it's a simple fix, since I'm hesitant to move to XCode 5 if I don't have to.

Any insights very much appreciated.

EDIT 1: I discovered that opening the app in 32-bit mode works on Yosemite.  So it's only 64-bit mode that has the problem.

EDIT 2: here is the output of otool as requested by Ken:

```
Load command 0
      cmd LC_SEGMENT_64
  cmdsize 72
  segname __TEXT
   vmaddr 0x00000001007f9000
   vmsize 0x0000000000225dba
  fileoff 0
 filesize 2251422
  maxprot rwx
 initprot rwx
   nsects 0
    flags (none)
Load command 1
        cmd LC_UNIXTHREAD
    cmdsize 184
     flavor x86_THREAD_STATE64
      count x86_THREAD_STATE64_COUNT
   rax  0x0000000000000000 rbx 0x0000000000000000 rcx  0x0000000000000000
   rdx  0x0000000000000000 rdi 0x0000000000000000 rsi  0x0000000000000000
   rbp  0x0000000000000000 rsp 0x0000000000000000 r8   0x0000000000000000
    r9  0x0000000000000000 r10 0x0000000000000000 r11  0x0000000000000000
   r12  0x0000000000000000 r13 0x0000000000000000 r14  0x0000000000000000
   r15  0x0000000000000000 rip 0x0000000100a1e3d8
rflags  0x0000000000000000 cs  0x0000000000000000 fs   0x0000000000000000
    gs  0x0000000000000000
```

Comment: Have you tried compiling your app with the latest Xcode?  Install it in a VM if you want to test it before you commit to a full upgrade.

Comment: As I mentioned, compiling with XCode 5 fixes the problem.  But I'd still like to understand what's going on, and if I can stay with XCode 4.5, I'd prefer to do so.

Comment: Ah, sorry, I overlooked the bit about Xcode 5 solving the problem. I advise you to do what we have done at our company: bite the bullet and move forward, especially if it is immediately observable that the new compiler fixes your problem. Let the desire to have your program build and run with no further fuss override your resistance to change.

Comment: Do you use any custom linker options? What's the output of `otool -lV path/to/YourApp.app/Contents/MacOS/YourAppExecutable`?

Comment: @KenThomases - please see edit above.  I don't really use custom linker options.  Thanks very much.

Comment: That's nowhere near a complete executable. I don't know why, but you're not building a proper x86_64 executable. For example, compare to the output of `otool -lV -arch i386 ...`.

Comment: Ok, thanks.  I'll investigate that.  But, as I mentioned above, the same exact executable runs fine on all prior versions of OS X.  So it still doesn't really answer my main question.

Comment: p.s., the output of -arch i386 looks pretty much the same to me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have encountered a very similar problem. otool -lV shows a similar segment structure. What I found out was that the issue was actually caused by executable packing using UPX (3.08). If you have applied UPX to your binary, run upx -d to decompress the binary and try running it on Yosemite again. The related discussions for my issue was described in a bug report I just filed:

https://sourceforge.net/p/upx/bugs/238/

Comment: You're right.  I just figured this out a couple days ago.  I completely forgot that we were using upx in our pipeline.  So you actually answered the question.  But Rhys Kidd's answer is also quite useful.

Comment: Just coming here to say thanks, this worked perfectly for me when trying to use PhantomJS with Selenium on a python script. It was complaining that it couldn't load the Ghostdriver and I saw the "Cannot enforce a hard page-zero" in the console, "upx -d phantomjs" solved it.

Answer (score 9):

Apple's kernel (xnu) from OS X 10.10 now enforces a 'hard page-zero' where in past this was not the case. Note this requirement is only for 64 bit MachO executables.

The issue would be resolved for your application by ensuring there is a __PAGEZERO segment. Importantly, this __PAGEZERO segment must have a vmaddr of 0x0 (NULL) and a vmsize of at least 0x1000. The specific name '__PAGEZERO' for the segment is not actually required, but most compilers will use it in this manner.

A hard (limited privileges) PAGEZERO makes NULL deference software vulnerabilities harder to exploit.

The following code snippets from the xnu source code explains:

```
// From xnu-2782.1.97/bsd/kern/mach_loader.c
load_return_t
load_machfile(
    struct image_params *imgp,
    struct mach_header  *header,
    thread_t        thread,
    vm_map_t        new_map,
    load_result_t       *result
)
{
    ...
    boolean_t enforce_hard_pagezero = TRUE;
    ...
    // Second vm_map_create() argument sets map->min_offset to zero.
    map = vm_map_create(pmap,
            0,
            vm_compute_max_offset((imgp->ip_flags & IMGPF_IS_64BIT)),
            TRUE);
    ...
    #if __x86_64__
    /*
     * On x86, for compatibility, don't enforce the hard page-zero restriction for 32-bit binaries.
     */         
    if ((imgp->ip_flags & IMGPF_IS_64BIT) == 0) {
        enforce_hard_pagezero = FALSE;
    }
    #endif
    /*
     * Check to see if the page zero is enforced by the map->min_offset.
     */
    // Note: vm_map_has_hard_pagezero(map, 0x1000) checks if map->min_offset >= 0x1000
    // Refer xnu-2782.1.97/osfmk/vm/vm_map.c
    if (enforce_hard_pagezero && (vm_map_has_hard_pagezero(map, 0x1000) == FALSE)) {
        if (create_map) {
            vm_map_deallocate(map); /* will lose pmap reference too */
        }
        printf("Cannot enforce a hard page-zero for %s\n", imgp->ip_strings);
        return (LOAD_BADMACHO);
    }
```

The raising of map->min_offset above zero happens in the segment loading code:

```
// From xnu-2782.1.97/bsd/kern/mach_loader.c
static
load_return_t
load_segment(
    struct load_command     *lcp,
    uint32_t            filetype,
    void *              control,
    off_t               pager_offset,
    off_t               macho_size,
    struct vnode            *vp,
    vm_map_t            map,
    int64_t             slide,
    load_result_t       *result
)
{
...
/*
 *  Round sizes to page size.
 */
seg_size = round_page_64(scp->vmsize);
map_size = round_page_64(scp->filesize);
map_addr = trunc_page_64(scp->vmaddr); /* JVXXX note that in XNU TOT this is round instead of trunc for 64 bits */

seg_size = vm_map_round_page(seg_size, vm_map_page_mask(map));
map_size = vm_map_round_page(map_size, vm_map_page_mask(map));

...
// This if test is key, checking for a 0x0 vmaddr, vmsize, and initprot and maxprot
// memory protections. 
// Note a segment name of "__PAGEZERO" is not actually required.
if (map_addr == 0 &&
    map_size == 0 &&
    seg_size != 0 &&
    (scp->initprot & VM_PROT_ALL) == VM_PROT_NONE &&
    (scp->maxprot & VM_PROT_ALL) == VM_PROT_NONE) {
    /*
     * For PIE, extend page zero rather than moving it.  Extending
     * page zero keeps early allocations from falling predictably
     * between the end of page zero and the beginning of the first
     * slid segment.
     */
    seg_size += slide;
    slide = 0;

    /*
     * This is a "page zero" segment:  it starts at address 0,
     * is not mapped from the binary file and is not accessible.
     * User-space should never be able to access that memory, so
     * make it completely off limits by raising the VM map's
     * minimum offset.
     */
    ret = vm_map_raise_min_offset(map, seg_size);


// From xnu-2782.1.97/osfmk/vm/vm_map.c
/*
 * Raise a VM map's minimum offset.
 * To strictly enforce "page zero" reservation.
 */
kern_return_t
vm_map_raise_min_offset(
    vm_map_t    map,
    vm_map_offset_t new_min_offset)
{
...
}
```

As to why your older Xcode 4.x does not set this up, it seems quite odd -- perhaps there is a project file setting, but the version of the clang compiler and linker which come with newer Xcode 5 (nay even Xcode 6) should more closely reflect the requirements of the modern OS X 10.10 kernel.

Note: There was a form of hard page-zero enforcement in earlier iOS releases, but not previously in OS X.

Valgrind, the tool suite which provides a number of debugging and profiling tools that help you make your programs faster and more correct, is also experiencing a related issue with this new OS X 10.10 kernel requirement: https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=339045

Comment: Interesting.  But Apple has certainly not ended support for 32-bit 10.7 apps.  If there's a 32-bit 10.7 app that runs on 10.6, 10.7, 10.8, 10.9, but not 10.10, that's a serious bug on Apple's part that needs to be reported and addressed.

Comment: Yes. The additional hard pagezero requirement only applies to 64bit apps. 32bit apps should still keep working fine. Per the OP's comments "I discovered that opening the app in 32-bit mode works on Yosemite. So it's only 64-bit mode that has the problem."

Comment: Ok, thanks very much for this information!  If you happen to find out exactly which project setting in XCode 4 might fix the problem, please let me know.  Otherwise I've been using XCode 6 and it works.

Comment: If all that's keeping you to XCode 4 is the interface (like I'd love to keep using XCode 3.2.6 ;)), you might be able to modify the compiler specs files (*.pbcompspec or so) to describe much more recent command line developer tools. That'd allow you to use them in your preferred IDE.